# Is it problematic to annotate Base and Child Service Classes?

Tags: spring, kotlin

*The programming language doesn't matter for this question: Kotlin and Java are fine.*

In my project I have inheritance of Service classes. While writing tests with Mockito it turns out, that `@MockBean` with the child classes doesn't work if I don't annotate the parent classes with `@Service` as well.

I like to know if its problematic in Spring to have child and parent classes annotated with `@Service`.

Any problems with that?:

```
@Service
abstract class BaseCrudService { ... }

@Transactional
@Service
class PersonService(...) : BaseCrudService { ... }
```

Notice that `BaseCrudService` and `PersonService` are both annotated with `@Service`

**Update**

Answering to M. Deinum's question, here is a full example:

Base class:

```
abstract class BaseCrudService {
    fun foo() {
        println("BaseCrudService#foo")
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
@Service
class PersonService : BaseCrudService() {
    fun bar() {
        println("PersonService#bar")
    }
}
```

Controller that uses the Service/child class:

```
@Controller
class MyController(val personService: PersonService) {
    fun myMethod() {
        println("MyController#myMethod")
        personService.foo()
        personService.bar()
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@WebMvcTest(MyController::class)
class MyControllerTest {
    @MockBean
    lateinit var personService: PersonService

    @Autowired
    lateinit var myController: MyController

    @Test
    fun testMyMethod() {
        myController.myMethod()
    }
}
```

Without annotating the base class with `@Service` the test output is:

```
MyController#myMethod
BaseCrudService#foo
```

As you can see, the method of the child class get mocked (no output) but the method of the base class get called (have output).

With the annotation `@Service abstract class BaseCrudService { ... }` the output is:

```
MyController#myMethod
```

The methods of the child and the parent class get mocked.

With annotating both, the parent and the child class with @Service, I get the expected behaviour. But I wonder if there is any problem to annotate both classes with @Service for Spring?

**Update 2**

In the previous example the problem is `BaseCrudService#foo` is **final**. In Kotlin methods are public, final by default, see this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/open-keyword#class-hierarchies).

Mockito didn't output any warning (may because of log settings). It is not able to mock final methods, see this [article](https://antonioleiva.com/mockito-2-kotlin/). After macking `BaseCrudService#foo` `open`, I can safely remove `@Service` from `BaseCrudService`. `@Service` to the parent class magically allows Mockito to mock the final method. So I need to find out a way of mocking a final method (this is not part of the question).

But regardless to Mockito, the question remains.

The article [Where Should the Spring @Service Annotation Be Kept?](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-service-annotation-placement) discusses the other way: Only the (abstract) parent class is annotated with `@Service` but the child class not.

Comment: Your problem description doesn't make sense. Why wouldn't it work, what is the problem you are running into?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Service
abstract class BaseCrudService { ... }
```

Here you have declared your class as abstract. Spring will not have a way of creating an instance as you have instructed it to do with `@Service`

Comment: Thanks! So Spring can safely ignore it? No performance problems or problems with tooling?